# Check with d'Alembert's ratio test the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1. 3. 5\dots(2n-1)}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check with delambre test the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1. 3. 5\dots(2n-1)}{3^n}.$$
So the first step I did is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(n+1)-1)}{3^{n+1}}  \frac{3^n}{2n-1} = \frac{(2n+1)3^n}{(2n-1)3^n3}=\frac{2n+1}{6n-3} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2n+1}{6n-3} = \frac{1}{3}<1 $$
its mean its Convergent. the answer that is not, what I did wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: I do not know about this Delambre test, but it's clear that if we set $a_n = \frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{3^n}$, then $a_{n+1} = a_\cdot \frac{2n+1}{3}$, which means that each term (apart from the second) is strictly larger than the last, and thus the sum cannot converge.

Comment: the demand is to check it with that : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: It is another name for the ratio test.

Comment: It is d'Alembert...

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the Ratio Test, you need to evaluate the quotient
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1*3*5*\cdots*(2(n+1)-1)/3^{n+1}}{1*3*5*\cdots*(2n-1)/3^n}.
$$
You should find that this limit equals $\infty$, which means that the series is divergent.

Your "first step" has three mistakes: it has a sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ that shouldn't be there; you included only the last terms $2(n+1)-1$ and $2n-1$ instead of all the factors contained in the summand; and the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ (not $\lim_{x\to\infty}$, there is no $x$) should be in every term, not just the last term.

Answer (score 0):

Put

$$a_n:=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot\ldots\cdot (2n-1)}{3^n}=\frac{(2n)!}{6^nn!}$$

and now d'Alembert:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{6^{n+1}(n+1)!}\frac{6^nn!}{(2n)!}=\frac16\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

and thus the series isn't convergent.